Google sheet Java API : How to sort sheet
After adding and updating some data in a Google Sheet, I want to sort the whole sheet by column D.
Yet my code has no effect (nor error message). Sorting via web interface works fine.
Setting a numerical index, trying any column (A, B, C,...) has no effect either.
SortSpec spec = new SortSpec();
spec.setSortOrder("ASCENDING");
spec.setDimensionIndex(('D'-'A')+1);
SortRangeRequest sortRequest = new SortRangeRequest();
sortRequest.setSortSpecs(Collections.singletonList(spec));
sortRequest.setRange(//
        new GridRange()//
                .setSheetId(0)//
                .setStartRowIndex(2)//Skipping table header row
);
Request req = new Request();
req.setSortRange(sortRequest);
BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest busReq = new BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest();
busReq.setRequests(Collections.singletonList(req));
// service is a instance of com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.Sheets
service.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(SPREADSHEET_ID, busReq).execute();

My dependencies :
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.apis/google-api-services-sheets -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-api-services-sheets</artifactId>
    <version>v4-rev20241008-2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.oauth-client/google-oauth-client -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-oauth-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.36.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-oauth-client-jetty</artifactId>
    <version>1.36.0</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.http-client/google-http-client-gson -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-http-client-gson</artifactId>
    <version>1.45.2</version>
</dependency>


Consider providing input and expected output as a plain text table  in the question. Click here to create a table easily, which is easy to copy/paste.
